# Computing the expectation of a quadratic matrix form involving Bernoulli and Gaussian distributed matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, probability-distributions, gaussian, expectation

I am working with two random matrices, $Z$ and $H$:

1. $Z$ is an $n \times K$ matrix with entries sampled i.i.d. from a Bernoulli distribution: $Z_{ij} \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(p)$.
2. $H$ is a $K \times K$ matrix with entries sampled from a multivariate Gaussian distribution.

I've defined a matrix product as:
$ \kappa = ZHZ^T $

Given that $Z$ and $H$ are independent, I'm interested in computing $E\kappa^2$.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Update**: I came across [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.00003.pdf) that seems somewhat related to my problem, especially since I'm using an Indian buffet process prior $P(Z)=IBP(\alpha)$. However, the approximate posterior distribution applied for computation of expectation is a Bernoulli with variable $p$. Here's the progress I've made so far, but I'm uncertain of its correctness. I'd love to get feedback on whether this is a structured way to compute the expectation:
I wrote $\mathrm{vec}(\kappa^2)=((Z \otimes Z) \mathrm{vec}(H) \otimes (Z \otimes Z) \mathrm{vec}(H)) \mathrm{vec}(I)$. Then I have $ \mathrm{vec}(H) \otimes \mathrm{vec}(H) = \mathrm{vec}(H \otimes H)$
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{vec}(\kappa^2) = (Z \otimes Z \otimes Z \otimes Z) \mathrm{vec}(H \otimes H)
\end{equation}
The fourth order moment is
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \mathbb{E}_{Z}\Big[Z \otimes Z \otimes Z \otimes Z\Big]&=\boldsymbol{p}\otimes\boldsymbol{p}\otimes\boldsymbol{p}\otimes\boldsymbol{p}+\mathfrak{S}_6\big[\mathrm{diag}(\boldsymbol{p}-\boldsymbol{p}^2)\otimes\boldsymbol{p}\otimes\boldsymbol{p}\big]\\
        &+\mathfrak{S}_3\big[\mathrm{diag}(\boldsymbol{p}-\boldsymbol{p}^2)\otimes\mathrm{diag}(\boldsymbol{p}-\boldsymbol{p}^2)\big]\\
&+\mathfrak{S}_4\big[\mathrm{diag}\big(\boldsymbol{p}-3\boldsymbol{p}^2+2\boldsymbol{p}^3\big)\otimes\boldsymbol{p}\big]\\
&+\mathrm{diag}\big(\boldsymbol{p}-7\boldsymbol{p}^2+12\boldsymbol{p}^3-6\boldsymbol{p}^4\big)
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
where $\mathfrak{S}_3\big[A\big]_{ikj}=A_{ijk}+A_{jki}+A_{kij}$ and $\mathfrak{S}_6\big[A\big]_{ikj}=A_{ijk}+A_{kij}+A_{jki}+A_{jik}+A_{kji}+A_{ikj}$ if $A=B\otimes C$. I could not find the definition of $\mathfrak{S}_4$ in the paper. Could anyone clarify the definition of $\mathfrak{S}_4$ and how is this moment computed? Furthermore, is my fist computational trick on track? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered simulation? How large are n and K?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I want to use it for variational inference which requires a lot of expectation computations.  I am open to a conversation to explain the problem more.

Comment: Do you really (mainly) only need to compare expectations for different cases (parameter values)? If so, you can use common random numbers for the different cases, which might make the differences in expectations fairly accurate even for relatively small sample size.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Could you elaborate on your point further? I already have a Gibbs sampling model that works well for small datasets. Going through all this computational hassle is because I'm trying to build a computationally efficient model that can handle N=10k or even more data points while I can have K=10-100.

Comment: Depends how the expectations are used.

Comment: @Dalek : You have an answer, as an explicit and rather simple expression in terms of $n,K,p$. So, what is the purpose of the "Update"?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\ka}{\kappa}\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}$We have $\ka^2=ZHZ^TZHZ^T$ and hence, for $i$ and $j$ in $[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$,
\begin{equation}
    (E\ka^2)_{ij}=\sum_{k,l,m,s,r}EZ_{ik}H_{kl}Z_{ml}Z_{ms}H_{sr}Z_{jr} \\ 
    =\sum_{k,l,m,s,r}EZ_{ik}Z_{ml}Z_{ms}Z_{jr}\, EH_{kl}H_{sr},  
\end{equation}
since $Z$ and $H$ are independent. Assume $n\ge2$; the case $n=1$ is much easier.

As the $H_{kl}$'s are iid $N(\mu,\si^2)$ for some real $\mu$ and some real $\si>0$, we have
$EH_{kl}H_{sr}=\mu^2+\si^2\,1(s=k,r=l)$. So,
\begin{equation}
    (E\ka^2)_{ij}=\mu^2 A_{ij}+\si^2 B_{ij},   
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    A_{ij}:=\sum_{m\in[n]}EZ_{i\cdot}Z_{m\cdot}^2 Z_{j\cdot}, \quad Z_{i\cdot}:=\sum_{k\in[K]}Z_{ik}, 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    B_{ij}:=\sum_{k,l,m}EZ_{ik}Z_{ml}Z_{mk}Z_{jl}.  
\end{equation}

So, it remains to compute $A_{ij}$ and $B_{ij}$. Moreover, by symmetry, $A_{ij}$ and $B_{ij}$ depend only on whether $i=j$ or not.

So, it suffices to compute $A_{11}$, $A_{12}$, $B_{11}$, $B_{12}$.

Note that
\begin{equation}
    A_{11}=(n-1)M_2^2+M_4,\quad A_{12}=(n-2)M_1^2 M_2+2M_3 M_1,
\end{equation}
where $M_r:=EZ_{1\cdot}^r$. Since $Z_{1\cdot}$ is a binomial random variable (r.v.) with parameters $k,p$, we easily find
\begin{equation}
    A_{11}=K p \left((K-1) p^3 \left(K^2 n-K (n+4)+6\right) \\ 
    +2 (K-1) p^2 (K
   (n+2)-6)+p (K (n+6)-7)+1\right),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    A_{12}=K^2 p^2 \left((K-1) p^2 (K n-4)+p (K (n+4)-6)+2\right). 
\end{equation}

It remains to compute $B_{11}$, $B_{12}$. To do this, note first that
\begin{equation}
    EZ_{ik}Z_{ml}Z_{mk}Z_{jl}=p^{\nu_{i,j,k,l,m}},
\end{equation}
where $\nu_{i,j,k,l,m}$ is the cardinality (that is, the number of distinct elements) of the set
\begin{equation}
    S_{i,j,k,l,m}:=\{(i,k),(m,l),(m,k),(j,l)\}. 
\end{equation}
The number $\nu_{i,j,k,l,m}$ depends on $i,j,k,l,m$ in a somewhat complicated manner, so that we have to consider a number of cases.

For given $i,j,k,l,m$, let $f=f_{i,j,k,l,m}$ be the map from the set $[4]=\{1,2,3,4\}$ onto $S$ such that $f(1)=(i,k)$, $f(2)=(m,l)$, $f(3)=(m,k)$, $f(4)=(j,l)$. The function $f_{i,j,k,l,m}$ naturally generates the equivalence $\sim\;=\;\sim_{i,j,k,l,m}$ over the set $[4]$ given by the formula $a\sim b\iff f(a)=f(b)$ for $a,b$ in $[4]$. This equivalence partitions the set $[4]$ into equivalence classes.
Then $\nu_{i,j,k,l,m}$ is the cardinality of this partition, that is, the number of equivalence classes for the equivalence $\sim_{i,j,k,l,m}$.

There are $15$ equivalences over the set $[4]$, and hence there are $15$ corresponding partitions of $[4]$. However, not all of these $15$ equivalences/partitions are generated by functions of the form $f_{i,j,k,l,m}$. Anyhow, for any equivalence, say $\approx$, of those $15$ equivalences, the condition $\approx\;=\;\sim_{i,j,k,l,m}$ is a (possibly empty) condition on $i,j,k,l,m$, which is expressible in terms of equalities between $i,j,k,l,m$.
Thus, we get the contribution of each of the $15$ equivalences/partitions into the sum $B_{ij}$.

Thus we finally get
\begin{equation}
    B_{11}=K p \left((K-1) (n-1) p^3+p (K+n-2)+1\right),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    B_{12}=K p^2 ((K-1) p+1) ((n-2) p+2). 
\end{equation}

Details of the calculations are provided in this [pdf image](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZ0z3GVZwtEXTO8WbpfiML8SRQrvauhsd3Xk) of a Mathematica notebook.

---

The more difficult part of these calculations is, of course, the calculations of $B_{11}$ and $B_{12}$, as they involve some combinatorics. The results of these calculations have been checked for some small values of $n$ and $K$.

Comment: @losifPinelis Thanks for your answer, I had a few comments exchanges which can clarify why I am interested in computing this expectation in general.

Comment: @Dalek : I do not understand how or whether the comments explaining why you are interested in computing this expectation relate to my answer.

Comment: Can you now finalize this matter according to these [guidelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

If $H$ has iid $N(0,1)$ entries, write $\kappa=\langle Z^TZ, H\rangle$ using the usual Frobenius inner product $\langle A,B\rangle = trace[A^TB]$. Conditionally on $Z$, $\kappa\sim N(0,\|Z^TZ\|_F^2)$ where $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm so that $E[\kappa^2]=E[\|Z^TZ\|_F^2]=\|E[Z^TZ]\|_F^2 + E[\|Z^TZ - E[Z^TZ]\|_F^2]$. The last two terms can be evaluated as a function of $\nu$ by treating the diagonal and off-diagonal entries separately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but $H$ is not a normal distribution with mean zero and variance 1.